# How to achieve Available zone aware for neutron-server

Tags: openstack-neutron, availability-zone

I have read the manual.

http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/networking-guide/adv-config-availability-zone.html

it tell us how to support multi AZ for dhcp/l3 router service.

But I still not know where the neutron server and qpid I will place in multi AZ environment.

Obviously, if we start  neutron-server/qpid processes in only one available zone, it is not a good solution, there's still a single point failure problem.

But I did not find any solution from official site of openstack, till now.

Anyone know that?

Regards,
Joe